# Can't add multiple selections to sub query in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I recently had a kind soul assist me in creating a calculation I could not wrap my head around...now I am facing an additional issue, apologies if it is redundant.  The below query works fine for the one article listed in the `WHERE` clause.  When I try to remove `MAX`from the initial `SELECT`and change the `WHERE` to `IN` and then add multiple selections, the calculation fails.  Below is the query with sample results for each scenario.

Thanks!

Query:

```
SELECT MAX(MATERIAL) AS [MATERIAL],
       SUM(COUNT_ATP_QTY)/ CONVERT(FLOAT,COUNT(1)) AS [FULL_SIZE_ATP]
FROM

 (

SELECT A.MATERIAL, 
       M.SIZE_LITERAL, 
       DATEPART(mm,AVAIL_DATE) AS [MONTH],
       ISNULL(a.avail_qty,'0') AS [Avail_Qty],
       COUNT(AVAIL_QTY) AS [COUNT_ATP_QTY]
FROM   VW_MM_SALES_GRID M 
LEFT OUTER JOIN VW_ATP_DOWNLOAD_NOREQCAT A 
ON A.MATERIAL = M.MATERIAL 
AND A.SIZE_LITERAL = M.SIZE_LITERAL
AND A.STOCK_CATEGORY IN ('A60381000','A60382000')
AND A.AVAIL_DATE BETWEEN GETDATE() AND GETDATE() + 90

WHERE  M.MATERIAL ='AA2721' AND  M.ACTIVE_FLAG IS NOT NULL

GROUP BY A.MATERIAL, 
         M.SIZE_LITERAL, 
         A.AVAIL_DATE, 
         A.AVAIL_QTY,
         A.STOCK_CATEGORY
         ) A
```

Results with the one MATERIAL:

```
 MATERIAL           FULL_SIZE_ATP
------------------ ----------------------
AA2721             0.666666666666667
```

If I add another article, AA2720:

```
MATERIAL           FULL_SIZE_ATP
------------------ ----------------------
NULL               0
AA2721             1
```

AA2720 should be 0 but the calculation changes for AA2721 and also the MATERIAL number doesn't populate for AA2720

Thanks!

Comment: Nothing in your question is called "article", so your question makes no sense.

Comment: apologies - I am relatively new to my role and they interchange 'article' and 'material' rather freely between departments...stuck in my old role.  Thanks again.

Comment: updated the query

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is anything wrong with changing the equals to an in for the inner select statement, but if you remove the 'max' on the outer query, you'll need to tell it how to group the resulting rows.  The inner query has a group by on it, but the outer query does not in what you've provided.

```
SELECT MATERIAL AS [MATERIAL],
SUM(COUNT_ATP_QTY)/ CONVERT(FLOAT,COUNT(1)) AS [FULL_SIZE_ATP]
FROM

(
SELECT A.MATERIAL, 
   M.SIZE_LITERAL, 
   DATEPART(mm,AVAIL_DATE) AS [MONTH],
   ISNULL(a.avail_qty,'0') AS [Avail_Qty],
   COUNT(AVAIL_QTY) AS [COUNT_ATP_QTY]
FROM   VW_MM_SALES_GRID M 
LEFT OUTER JOIN VW_ATP_DOWNLOAD_NOREQCAT A 
ON A.MATERIAL = M.MATERIAL 
AND A.SIZE_LITERAL = M.SIZE_LITERAL
AND A.STOCK_CATEGORY IN ('A60381000','A60382000')
AND A.AVAIL_DATE BETWEEN GETDATE() AND GETDATE() + 90

WHERE  M.MATERIAL in ('AA2721', 'OtherValue') AND  M.ACTIVE_FLAG IS NOT NULL

GROUP BY A.MATERIAL, 
     M.SIZE_LITERAL, 
     A.AVAIL_DATE, 
     A.AVAIL_QTY,
     A.STOCK_CATEGORY

) A
GROUP BY MATERIAL
```